# Image creation for managed cloud deployments

Tags: aks, sitecore-managed-cloud

We are currently creating our images to deploy to managed cloud (aks).  Sitecore provide us with an acr for each environment.  Is it best practice to create 1 image per role (cm, cd) per environment or do you create 1 image per role (cm, cd) and deploy the same image to each environment? How is everyone handling this?

Comment: I haven't used managed cloud before, but would be interested to see what you/others went with. Seems to me one image per role is the obvious solution, as that allows you to push through environments and have confidence it works.  How does the push to ACR work? Is it a web hook and branch per environment? With the webhook triggering ACR task to build and push to corresponding environment?